# Scala default Set Implementation

Tags: scala

I can see that from Scala documentation scala.collection.immutable.Set is only a trait. Which one on the Set implementation is used by default ? HashSet or TreeSet (or something else) ?

I would like to know/plan the running time of certain functions.

Example:

```
 scala> val s = Set(1,3,6,2,7,1)
 res0: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 6, 2, 7, 3)
```

- What would be the running time of s.find(5), O(1) or O(log(n)) ?
- Since same apply for Map, what is the best way to figure this out ?

Comment: Looking at the type Hierarchy, there seems to be specialized sets from empty up to 4 elements, and then it goes to a hashset. I'm writing this as a comment since I haven't tested it.

Comment: @Luciano - You are correct, and it's easy to test with `Set(1,2).getClass` and the like.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

By looking at the source code, you can find that sets up to four elements have an optimized implementation provided by `EmptySet`, `Set1`, `Set2`, `Set3` and `Set4`, which simply hold the single values.

For example here's `Set2` declaration (as of scala 2.11.4):

```
class Set2[A] private[collection] (elem1: A, elem2: A) extends AbstractSet[A] with Set[A] with Serializable
```

And here's the `contains` implementation:

```
def contains(elem: A): Boolean =
  elem == elem1 || elem == elem2
```

or the `find` implementation

```
override def find(f: A => Boolean): Option[A] = {
  if (f(elem1)) Some(elem1)
  else if (f(elem2)) Some(elem2)
  else None
}
```

Very straightforward.

For sets with more than 4 elements, the underlying implementation is an `HashSet`. We can easily verify this in the REPL:

```
scala> Set(1, 2, 3, 4).getClass
res1: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set4

scala> Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).getClass
res0: Class[_ <: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]] = class scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet
```

That being said, `find` must always iterate over the whole `HashSet`, since it's unsorted, so it will be `O(n)`.
Conversely, a lookup operation like `contains` will be `O(1)` instead.

[Here's a more in-depth reference](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) about performance of scala collections in general.

Speaking of `Map`, pretty much the same concepts apply. There are optimized `Map` implementations up to 4 elements, and then it's an `HashMap`.