# Scala: Whats the difference between "Map" vs "Set"?

Tags: scala, dictionary, set

I'm just starting to learn Scala and I can see those to types: Map and Set. For me both works like dictionary. When should I use each?

The example I was following was using "Set[(String, String)]". Which for me looks similar the way Maps is used.

Comment: Please show us how you use Set as a dictionary.

Comment: Yeah right.. how in the world are you using Set as a Map??

Comment: With clever use of `.hashCode`, you could probably make a Set of 2-tuples behave like a key-value map, but it would be incredibly weird, to say the least.

Comment: As Silvio Mayolo said, the example that I was following it was something like "Set[(String, String)]". That's why I'm confusing Sets with Maps.

Comment: A `Set[String,String]` would allow the same key for multiple values. I don't see how that would work as a dictionary. The only similarity I see is that a `Map` doesn't allow duplicate keys and a `Set` doesn't allow duplicate elements. After that they're very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Map` stores a key and a value, and given the key, returns the value (if the key is present in the map). So, a dictionary.

```
val m = Map("sky"->"blue", "grass"->"green")
```

A `Set` stores a key, and given the key, returns a Boolean indicating whether or not the key is in the set. It's not a dictionary, as there's no value associated with a key - just present/no-present.

```
val s = Set("sky"->"blue", "grass"->"green")
```

So a `Set[(String, String)]` is a set of tuples of two Strings. Although it looks like a '(key, value)` pair, it's not - you have to pass the whole pair to the set to check for membership.  You can't just pass the "key" part.

```
s("sky")  // error
s("sky"->"blue") // true
s("sky"->"red") // false
```

A `Map[String, String]` is a map where both the key and the value are Strings. But you can pass the `key` and get back the `value`.

```
m("sky") // "blue"
m("green") // Error
m("grass") // "green"
m("rock") // Error
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. Makes more sense to me.

Answer (score -3):

The immutable Map is a TrieMap. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). So it contains a Trei consisting of key-value pairs.

The immutable Set is a TrieSet. It uses only keys.. there is no value part.
Also, check [this explanation on Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901866/scala-default-set-implementation).

It is important to use Tries as it allows immutability, and thus, concurrency. There is no such thing in Java.

Comment: That's not really answering the OP's question, though