# What is the return type of toSet in Scala

Tags: scala, collections, set, hashset, scala-collections

Suppose I have a Scala array `arr` of `Int`. Consider `arr.toSet`. I know that `toSet` returns a `Set` object. Is this `Set` a `HashSet`, or `TreeSet` in default?

Comment: It depends on size: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/sets.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901866/scala-default-set-implementation

Comment: Why do you care about the implementation detail? If you need an specific type of Set you can `arr.to(TreeSet)` - BTW, you are confusing **types** with **classes**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Maybe because different implementations have different performance with respect to some operations?

Comment: @DmytroMitin fair, that is why I said that if you want an specific kind of Set, ask explicitly for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Set.scala

Up to 4 elements `EmptySet`, `Set1`, ..., `Set4` (like tuples), then `HashSet`.

Answer (score 5):

The compile-time *type* of value returned by `toSet` is `Set`

```
def toSet[B >: A]: immutable.Set[B]
```

however the runtime *class* of object returned by `toSet` might differ which we can check using Scala REPL

```
Array(1).toSet.getClass                 // class immutable.Set$Set1
Array(1, 2).toSet.getClass              // class immutable.Set$Set2
Array(1, 2, 3).toSet.getClass           // class immutable.Set$Set3
Array(1, 2, 3, 4).toSet.getClass        // class immutable.Set$Set4
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).toSet.getClass     // class immutable.HashSet
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).toSet.getClass  // class immutable.HashSet
...
```

which outputs

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have a Scala array `arr` of `Int`. Consider `arr.toSet`. I know that `toSet` returns a `Set` object. Is this `Set` a `HashSet`, or `TreeSet` in default?

Neither. It is a [`scala.collection.immutable.Set`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html).

Here's [the documentation for `scala.Array.toSet`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#toSet[B>:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B]) (which is actually [`scala.collection.IterableOnceOps.toSet`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html#toSet[B>:A]:scala.collection.immutable.Set[B])):

> ```scala
> def toSet[B >: A]: Set[B]
> ```

As you can see, it clearly specifies that the return type is `Set`.