# Does Scala automatically change order of data in sets?

Tags: scala

I was looking at a set example for scala and I noticed that when states3 was created the compiler changed the order of the members of that set, Wyoming was in 3rd place and now its last. Could someone please explain why this happens?

```
scala> val states = Set("Alabama", "Alaska", "Wyoming")
states: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Alabama, Alaska, Wyoming)
scala> val states2 = states + "Virginia"
states2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] =
Set(Alabama, Alaska, Wyoming, Virginia)
scala> val states3 = states2 + ("New York", "Illinois")
states3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] =
Set(Alaska, Virginia, Alabama, New York, Illinois, Wyoming)
```

example taken from Programming Scala: Scalability = Functional Programming + Objects by Dean Wampler

Comment: Sets do **not** guarantee order. They guarantee to answer the question if an element is a member of the set or not.

Comment: You can use a Set that is specifically ordered, but most likely, if you use a HashSet or something like that, it'll be kind of ordered according to the hashcode and not the order of insertion. See [Scala default Set Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901866/scala-default-set-implementation) and [Can I rely on the order of items in a Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245713/scala-can-i-rely-on-the-order-of-items-in-a-set)

Comment: @MarioGalic  thank you that really helped clear things up for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set` on its own guarantee only, that the same element cannot be inserted twice (by the same we understand `true` result  of `==`/`.equals` comparison with `.hashcode` matching `.equals` to filfil the contract). If your type is just `Set`, there are no guarantees about tha order which most likely means that it will be `HashSet` which optimizes internal structure towards easy `.hashcode` comparison.

If you want to preserve order of inserting (assuming that the same element inserted twice won't change the order of its first insertion) then use `ListSet`.

If you want to order element according to some `Ordering` use `SortedSet`.

Answer (score 5):

> Does Scala automatically change order of data in sets?

No, it doesn't for the simple reason that `Set`s don't *have* an order, and you can't change something that doesn't exist.

Note that this is nothing specific to Scala, or even to programming. That's part of the nature of sets in general.